# To find the length of the shortest path that begins at $(-1,1)$, touches the x-axis and then ends at a point on the parabola $(x-y)^2 = 2(x + y −4)$:

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

This is a question of a parabola but to solve it I need the coordinates of the vertex and focus which at present I'm unable to deduce in this form. I have learnt some standard form such as $ y^2=4ax$ and other such forms. Can anyone explain how to locate the vertex, focus and also how to get the equation of the directrix.

Actual question : The length of the shortest path that begins at the point $(-1, 1)$, touches the x-axis and then ends at a point on the parabola $(x-y)^2 = 2(x + y −4)$, is?

Comment: I think you would need to first find the shortest path from a given point $(x,y)=(x_0, 0)$ to the parabola. I'm not 100% sure but it could be useful to transform $s=x+y, t=x-y$.

Comment: For the first part, do a change of rectillinear variables $Y = x-y, X = x+y$ to get it into the form $Y^2 = 4aX$, find the vertex and focus there, then change back to $x,y-$coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parabola equation is

$ (x - y)^2 = 2 (x + y - 4) $

Reflect the point $(-1, 1)$ about the $x$ axis.  You will get $(-1, -1)$.

Now we need to connect $(-1,-1)$ to the parabola by a line segment that is perpendicular to its curve.

Compute the slope of the tangent to the parabola by differnetiating with respect to $x$.  This will give

$ 2 (x - y) (1 - y' ) = 2 (1 + y') $

Hence

$ y' = \dfrac{x - y - 1}{x - y + 1} $

Now the line segment connecting $(x,y)$ to $(-1, -1)$ has a slope of

$ m = \dfrac{y+1}{x+1} $

The product of $m $ and $y'$ has to be equal to $(-1) $.

$ -1 = \dfrac{ (y+1) (x - y - 1)}{ (x+1)(x - y + 1) } $

i.e.

$ - (x + 1)(x - y + 1) = (y + 1)(x - y - 1) $

Expand,

$ -( x^2 - x y + x + x - y + 1) = x y - y^2 - y + x - y - 1 $

This simplifies to

$ - x^2 + y^2 - 3 x + 3 y = 0 $

This factors into

$ (y - x) ( 3 + y + x) = 0 $

This implies either $ y = x$  or $ x + y = -3 $

If $ x + y = -3 $, the plug this into the parabola equation

$ (x - y)^2 = 2 ( -3 - 4 )  $

which has no real solutions.

The other solution is $ x = y $ and this gives

$ 0 = 2 (2 y - 4) $

So $ y = x = 2 $

Connect $(2, 2)$ to $(-1, -1)$ gives the minimum distance as $3 \sqrt{2}$

Comment: Thanks for the solution but can you clarify as to why we need to obtain it's reflection about X-axis?

Comment: Because the path from (-1,1) to the parabola has to touch the X-axis.  So the path is comprised of a segment from $(x, y)$ to $( x_1, 0)$ and a second from $(x_1, 0)$ to $(-1, 1)$.  The trick here is that the distance from $(x_1, 0)$ to $(-1, 1)$ is the same as the distance from $(x_1, 0)$ to $(-1, -1)$.   And this means that the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(-1,1)$ is the same as the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(-1,-1)$, but in the latter one, we have no restrictions, and the shortest path will clearly be the straight line segment from $(x,y)$ to $(-1,-1)$.

Comment: Thank you @DS , I've corrected my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with finding vertex and focus of the parabola
you can rewrite the the equation $y^2=4ax$ as :
$$(\text{distance from x axis})^2=4a(\text{distance from y axis})$$
in this case x axis is the axis of parabola and y axis is tangent at vertex.

we know that distance of a point $(x_1,y_1)$ from a line $y=mx+c$ is $$|\frac{mx_1-y_1+c}{\sqrt{m^1+1}}|$$

here judging from the equation tangent at vertex is $x+y-4=0$ and axis of parabola is $x=y$

so equation of parabola should be of form :
$$\left(\frac{x-y}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2=4a|\frac{x+y-4}{\sqrt2}|$$
$$(x-y)^2=4a\sqrt 2 (x+y-4)$$
from the given equation we know that $4a\sqrt2=2$ so $a=\frac{\sqrt2}{4}$

by solving two lines we know that vertex is (2,2) and by using some geometry and value of a we can calculate that focus is $\left(\frac{9}{4},\frac{9}{4}\right)$

Comment: yes sorry for the mistake